# How To Solve Error: ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required in Django on Windows?

Tags: django, python-3.x, windows

I follow the tutorial from Traversy Media on Youtube videos. When I put the command

> python manage.py migrate

Then I got such an error like this:

```
C:\Users\Acer\Project\djangoproject>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__
init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\db\models\options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length(
))
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\db\utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__
init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 36, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you hav
e %s.' % Database.__version__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is requ
ired; you have 0.9.3.
```

Btw, I already install the C++ Build Visual Studio from another error that I got, and I also installed already the **mysqlclient-1.4.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl** to get it done. But still, it gives me such an error.

Please help me, and thank you for those who already respond on this.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: I don't understand sir, i am a beginner in Python. And just started learning Django. I follow the tutorial from Traversy Media on Youtube btw on his Django tutorial. Then when i put, command 'python manage.py migrate' i got an error like showing above.

Comment: That would be a no :)

Comment: You need to use a virtual environment! I'll update my answer with a quick rundown.

Comment: @CalebGoodman Ok sir

Comment: do a bit of research on what a "virtual environment" is, then try my answer and let me know if it works!  good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a virtual environment?  If you have no idea what I'm talking about, see [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-virtual-environments-in-python--cms-28272) blog for a good explanation for what a virtual environment is.

For this example I will be using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) but any virtual environment will do.

steps:

- open CMD/Terminal and `cd` into your project folder
- run `virtualenv ./env && source env/bin/activate 
  (this create the`env` directory, and starts your virtual environment)
- run `pip3 install django mysqlclient`
  (this installs `django` and `mysqlclient` into your virtual environment)

Now your migrations should work as expected.

Remember that you have to run `source env/bin/activate` *every* time that you open a new CMD/Terminal window (inside of your root project folder)

Comment: But is says mine already update. This is what i got after running "pip3 install --upgrade mysqlclient" in cmd

'C:\Users\Acer\Project\djangoproject>pip3 install --upgrade mysqlclient
Requirement already up-to-date: mysqlclient in c:\users\acer\appdata\local\progr
ams\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (1.4.4)'

Comment: @aldo is `pip3` updating the same version of python that you are running? `python -m pip ...` is the best thing to run to make sure you are updating the same version that you are running

Comment: @aldo This seems to be a reoccurring problem that windows users are having with Django, since I've seen this question asked several times (and no accepted answers).  I personally use Mac so I can't be of much help.

Comment: @aldo run `python -m pip install --upgrade mysqlclient`?

Comment: @CalebGoodman Do you still got an error after turning your OS into Mac?

Comment: @IainShelvington after put 'python -m pip install --upgrade mysqlclient' I still got the message if mysqlclient is already up-to-date

Comment: @aldo are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: I once install virtualenv at Folder djangoproject which i install for my Django tutorial sir

Answer (score 0):

libmariadb-dev-compat: /usr/bin/mysql_config Debian

Comment: Please provide more elaborate answer.